# How to get file names of checked checkBoxes of TreeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, nodes, treeviewitem

My task is to create a program which takes a path and shows the directories, including files with a file extension filter. The files shall then be read and their lines (LOC) have to get counted. Only checked files shall be read.

I have used TreeViewItem to display the files and added a CheckBox to each file's header. I haven't figured out how to determine whether a file is checked or not yet. I already looked around on stack overflow but couldn't find something fitting.

So basically I need to get the checked file names to read out how many lines they contain.

involving methods:

```
private void ListDirectory(System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            treeView.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            treeView.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PathException(path);
        }
    }
    catch (PathException pExc)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(pExc.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    }
}

private TreeViewItem CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    TreeViewItem directoryNode = new TreeViewItem {
        Header = directoryInfo.Name
    };

    directoryNode.Foreground = Brushes.BlueViolet;
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        try
        {
            directoryNode.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Certain files could not be opened", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            break;
        }
    }

    var cbox_ex_array = comboBox_extensions.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(' ');
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles(cbox_ex_array[1]))
    {
        TreeViewItem ti = new TreeViewItem {
            Header = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox() {
                        IsChecked = true, Content = file.Name
            }
        };

        ti.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        directoryNode.Items.Add(ti);
    }

    return directoryNode;
}

private void button_display_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListDirectory(treeView, textBox_path.Text);
}

private void button_get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here I'd like to gather all checked files in form of a list/array
}
```

That's how it currently looks:
[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDqRq.png)

Comment: If you're in WPF you should have a ViewModel layer with for example a FileVM class that contains a list of FileVM, a name and so on and a property ShouldBeRead. In the xaml your TreeView's ItemsSource is bound to a list of FileVM and you set a DataTemplate to display FileVM as TreeViewItem and bind the ShouldBeRead property to TreeViewItem's IsSelected DP. At the end, all you have to do is make a search in the FileVM's collection to find who's checked

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using **ItemCollection** and typecasting its items to **TreeViewItem**, then asking if the header is a **CheckBox**

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> filesToRead = new Dictionary<int, string>();

private void button_get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (filesToRead.Count > 0)
        {
            filesToRead.Clear();
        }

        GetCheckedItems(treeView.Items);

        if (filesToRead.Count > 0)
        {
            label_files_r.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            label_files_r.Content = "files received: " + filesToRead.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            label_files_r.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No files found!", "Attention", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    private void GetCheckedItems(ItemCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (var itemRaw in collection)
        {
            var item = (TreeViewItem)itemRaw;

            if (item.Header is System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)
            {
                var checkBox = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)item.Header;
                if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
                    filesToRead.Add((filesToRead.Count + 1), checkBox.Content.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                GetCheckedItems(item.Items);
            }
        }
    }
```